# How do I change what it means for objects to be duplicate in a set?

Tags: java, collections, set

I want to store a set of Edges:

```
class Edge {
    int u;
    int v;
    char symbol;
}
```

The problem is that it's possible for two `Edge` objects to have the same `u`, `v` and `symbol`, but they can both be stored in a HashSet because they're not the same object even though I want them to be considered the same object.  How can I store only one object that has a unique (`u`, `v`, `symbol`) in a `Set`?

Comment: Maybe override equals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the following two methods `equals` and `hashcode`.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Edge)) return false;
    // return true if they are the same, otherwise false
}

public int hashCode() {
    // return an int that represents similarity
    // Example: name.hashCode(), if they are the same with the same name
}
```

Comment: i would use `instaanceof` rather than comparing classes using `equals` in case there are subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of set you want to use; The below applies for HashSet for instance, but not for any subclass of SortedSet

By overriding [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

```
class Edge {
    int u;
    int v;
    char symbol;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + symbol;
        result = prime * result + u;
        result = prime * result + v;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        Edge other = (Edge) obj;

        return symbol == other.symbol && u == other.u && v == other.v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `equals()`. Like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   //do the comparison here; remember to cast obj to Edge
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it in the HashMap, you also need to override hashCode() like @greedybuddha said.